# ANTLR4 Missing Rule Definition

Tags: antlr4, antlrworks

I have been hacking away at my ANTLR4 grammar trying to eliminate all of its ambiguities, lexer rule error at a time. Nothing I seem to do fixes the problems. These lexer rules in particular that give me the same error are as follows:

```
Identifier: Letter (Letter | Digit | Und)+;
Keyword   : Letter+;
Param: Number | Identifier;
Statement: Keyword Lpr Param+ Rpr;
Block: Lbc Statement+ Rbc;
```

As you might have noticed, one token they all have in common is *Letter*. This and other tokens are defined as:

```
fragment Digit: '0'..'9';
fragment Letter: ('A'..'Z');
Und: '_';
Lpr: '(';
Rpr: ')';
```

I can't find how this could cause an ambiguity, unless ANTLR doesn't allow for multiple definition with potentially identical outcomes.

Answer (score 0):

ANTLR only (really) works with unambiguous grammars. Certain left-recursions are allowed and predicates and lexer modes can be used to handle/avoid ambiguities.

ANTLR will, however, `allow for multiple definition with potentially identical outcomes`.

It does this by always selecting the first such conflicting rule. The remaining conflicting rules are shadowed, meaning that for all practical purposes, they do not exist. Almost certainly, a very undesirable result.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up for me. Unfortunately that means my initial question still stands. What could be causing all of those rules to be throwing the same error?

Comment: All of the rules that ultimately depend on `Keyword`, which is entirely shadowed, will fail with the same error (`Number` does not appear to be defined). Just switching the order of `Identifier` and `Keyword` will not work (all identifiers that contain just letters will be consumed as keywords). Typically, keywords would be explicitly specified followed by the catchall rule, such as the `Identifier` rule; meaning that any `Letter+` not explicitly named as a keyword is an identifier.

Comment: I get the idea now. The issue is that I'm trying to define a grammar that allows for the definition of additional keywords (keywords will basically be function names) so I was trying to define only the syntax in the lexer and define the semantics in the parser.

Comment: So it boils down to the classic keywords vs. identifier problem. This has been discussed already a few times. Use your prefered search engine to find possible solutions (including my [own discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/antlr-discussion/RsQYZjzf2Bc) on the ANTLR mailing list).

Comment: Function names are not really keywords (from a grammar POV). They are identifiers that are structurally identifiable in parser rules as representing function names. Likewise, variables are identifiers, but appear in different structural relations as defined in their own parser rules. The resulting parse-tree provides an explicit (and easy to use) basis for distinguishing the kind of identifier.